# jQuery move div contents instead of clone

Tags: jquery, clone, move

The code I'm using now just clones the ".comment_post" div and inserts the form under the comment.

What I would like to do (if possible) is to "move" the ".comment_post" div to the new location instead of cloning it.

Any suggestions on how I can do this?

#### HTML

```
<div class="comment-post">
<form id="addCommentForm" method="post" action="">
<div class="avatar"><img src="http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/ee61e6c16/?s=36&r=g&d=mm" /></div>
<textarea name="txt" id="txt" class="txtcomment"></textarea><button class="btnComment" type="button">Send</button>
</form></div>

<div class="comment">
<span class="avatar"><img src="http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/ee61e6c16/?s=36&r=g&d=mm"></span>
<span class="poster">Jake</a></span><span class="time">5 months ago</span>
<div class="text">just a test comment ...</div>
<div class="reply"><a href="#" onclick="reply(174);">Reply</a></div><div id="new-174"></div>
</div>

<div class="comment">
<span class="avatar"><img src="http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/ee61e6c16/?s=36&r=g&d=mm"></span>
<span class="poster">Jake</a></span><span class="time">5 months ago</span>
<div class="text">another comment ...</div>
<div class="reply"><a href="#" onclick="reply(175);">Reply</a></div><div id="new-175"></div>
</div>
```

#### JS

```
reply = function(id){
    if(!$('#new-'+id+' .comment-post').length) {
        $('.comment-post:first').clone().attr('id', id).appendTo($('#new-'+id));
        $('#new-'+id+' .txtcomment').focus();
        $('#new-'+id+' .txtcomment').autosize();
        $('#new-'+id+' .txtcomment').bind('keydown', charcounter);
        $('#new-'+id+' .txtcomment').bind('keyup', charcounter);
    }
    else
    {
        $('#new-'+id+' .comment-post').remove();
    }          
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just omit `.clone()`:

```
$('.comment-post:first').attr('id', id).appendTo($('#new-'+id));
```

When you use `.appendTo()` or `.append()` to append an element to a single target it is moved, not copied. (Up to you whether you also want to omit the `.attr()` part.)

Also you can supply just a selector string to `.appendTo()` rather than creating a new jQuery object and passing it:

```
$('.comment-post:first').attr('id', id).appendTo('#new-'+id);
```

Answer (score 3):

Change remove the clone() from your js code.

```
$('.comment-post:first').attr('id', id).appendTo($('#new-'+id));
```

Answer (score 3):

I know it is already solved, but for research purpose, follow a brief explanation:

**.append()**

> If an element selected this way is inserted into a single location
>   elsewhere in the DOM, it will be moved into the **END** of the target (not cloned):

```
$( "#div_container" ).append( $( "#div_moved" ) );
```

http://api.jquery.com/append/

**.prependTo()**

> If an element selected this way is inserted into a single location
>   elsewhere in the DOM, it will be moved into the **BEGGINING** of the target (not cloned):

```
$( "#div_moved" ).prependTo( $( "#div_container" ) );
```

http://api.jquery.com/prependto/

**.clone()**

> Create a deep copy of the set of matched elements.

```
$( ".div_cloned" ).clone().prependTo( $( "#div_container" ) );;
```

http://api.jquery.com/clone/

Comment: Thank you for explaining the differences!

Answer (score 1):

Working DEMO here http://jsfiddle.net/yeyene/WTuRY/1/

You can use `.html()` to get the whole html contents inside DIV.

## JQUERY

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('a#move').on('click', function(){
        $('#newDIV').html($('.comment-post').html());
        $('.comment-post').remove();     
    });   
});
```